# WP_Query Get all Posts by category with Tags included

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to get all posts in a category with their respective tags.

Using 
`$args = array('numberposts' => 100,'category_name' => 'someCategory' );
      $arr = get_posts( $args );`

But the tags related to each post are not in the WP_Post Objects array.

Unclear if I need to set this as an additional arg or call another function within the loop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to call another function within your loop, it could be `get_the_terms()`, example:

```
foreach( $arr as $post ) {
    // function will return an array of objects of assigned tags
    print_r( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'post_tag' ) );
}
```